# UIImagePickerController issue when zoom camera on iPad with iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, ipad, zooming, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8.1

I have a problem with UIImagePickerController on iPad with iOS 8.1. Everything works OK while I don't use zoom in on camera control. If iPad oriented in Landscape mode the overlay view with camera preview is moved to the side of screen and became 768px width. In Portrait mode everything works fine.

I use standard Apple example PhotoPicker to show camera control. And the standard example have the same issue.

My UIImagePickerController initialization:

```
var imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();

imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
imagePicker.AllowsEditing = false;
imagePicker.ShowsCameraControls = false;

imagePicker.CameraOverlayView = this.overlayView;
imagePicker.View.AutoresizingMask = this.View.AutoresizingMask;
this.overlayView.Frame = imagePicker.View.Bounds; // overlayView - root view in ViewController that presents camera

this.View.AddSubview(imagePicker.View);
```

1. ![before zoom]http://i59.tinypic.com/2ducf37.jpg
2. ![after zoom]http://i59.tinypic.com/29b0adw.png

Do you have any ideas how it could be fixed? I spent a lot of time googling, but didn't find solution. I tried Autoresize mode in xib, I tried Autoresizing masks also, and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue too.  I don't know if this helps your particular situation, but after doing some digging around, I found that the [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406-SW1) explicitly states that the UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode **only**.  This would explain why the camera preview does not want to resize itself after an orientation change.

Comment: Yes, I found this. But in my app running on iOS 7.1, iOS 8.0 & 8.0.2 it works fine.
As a result I rewrote my camera with using AVCapture and made manual zooming with Pinch gesture, because all tricks with frames, autoresizing masks and auto layout constraints didn't come with acceptable result.

Comment: The image picker odes support landscape insofar as the built-in camera app rotates the ui and also when setting `ShowsCameraControls` to `true`, the controls rotate as expected and zooming works. I think the statement that the class only supports portrait mode relates more to selecting pictures from the gallery, otherwise this class would be somewhat useless.
I rather think this is a bug in iOS.